# Knowledge Article Deployment Error

Tags: deployment, knowledge, compact-layout

I receive the following errors when I attempt to deploy the metadata for 3 new article types (their objects). I understand the error is due to the compactLayoutAssignment, but I don't know what the actual issue is or how to fix it.

```
File Name:    objects/External_QA__kav.object
Full Name:  External_QA__kav
Action:  NO ACTION
Result:  FAILED
Problem: Cannot specify: compactLayoutAssignment for Knowledge Article Type

File Name:    objects/Internal_QA__kav.object
Full Name:  Internal_QA__kav
Action:  NO ACTION
Result:  FAILED
Problem: Cannot specify: compactLayoutAssignment for Knowledge Article Type

File Name:    objects/Overview__kav.object
Full Name:  Overview__kav
Action:  NO ACTION
Result:  FAILED
Problem: Cannot specify: compactLayoutAssignment for Knowledge Article Type
```

I am on a Enterprise Edition development sandbox (cs8 - Spring 14), deploying to an Enterprise Edition full sandbox (cs7 - Spring 14). I am using Eclipse (v. Kepler) with the Salesforce IDE plug-in (v 29.0.0.201310181333).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by upgrading my SF Plug-in to version 30. Support also confirmed that is the resolution.

I'm still a little confused as some of their [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/customobject.htm) states Compact Layout Assignment is available on version 29 or higher.

[image]